# Python 3.x - Separating Long Binary String to Short

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had a question about dividing long binary string to shorter ones.

For example, I am trying to convert...

```
000000100000000011000000100000000010000000100000000001
```

to...

```
000000100000000011
000000100000000010
000000100000000001
```

So basically, I am looking for a python command so that the program can create new line every 18 digits and if possible, introduce a space between first 7 digits and last 11 digits. And then reverse them all back to longer string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will divide your long string into shorter strings.

```
>>> s = '000000100000000011000000100000000010000000100000000001'
>>> print('\n'.join([s[i:i + 7] + ' ' + s[i + 7:i + 18] for i in range(0,len(s),18)]))
0000001 00000000011
0000001 00000000010
0000001 00000000001
```

This will also put in the spaces you mentioned.

To go in the opposite direction, we can do the following:

```
>>> f = '0000001 00000000011\n0000001 00000000010\n0000001 00000000001'
>>> print(''.join([c for c in f if c in '01']))
000000100000000011000000100000000010000000100000000001
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a commend to reverse them back together to "s" once thy have been splitted?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Basically, I am editing binary value to change item number in game. The game uses hex values in the save file. So if I want to convert binary number to hex, I thought I need the long binary string again.

Comment: Edited to add the reverse operation.  If this helped you, click the check mark button to mark this as accepted so others know it helped you too.

Comment: For the replacement `f.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')` is faster, even though the difference would be imperceptible for such small strings.

Comment: Thank you again Brien. I was just waiting for reverse operation command before selecting yours as my desired answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
val = '000000100000000011000000100000000010000000100000000001'
short_val = ''
for i range(len(val) - 1):
    if i % 16 == 0:
       print(short_val)
       short_val = ''
    else:
       short_val += val[i]
```